# How to solve repeating Xorg crash?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, crash

After about a year of using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with very few crashes I have had a number of crashes over the last week. They all product the same error code as listed below. When the crash happens the screen goes blank and after about 10 seconds the login screen shows up again. When I login back in there is a new session. It does not crash every time I use the computer but it is frequent enough.

Would really appreciate any insight in how to prevent this crash happening.

The following is what was in the `/var/log/apport.log` file:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 13288) Mon Sep 28 20:27:45 2015: called for pid 2524, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615 
ERROR: apport (pid 13288) Mon Sep 28 20:27:45 2015: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited 
ERROR: apport (pid 13288) Mon Sep 28 20:27:45 2015: executable: /usr/bin/Xorg (command line "/usr/bin/X -core :0-seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch")
ERROR: apport (pid 13288) Mon Sep 28 20:27:45 2015: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment 
ERROR: apport (pid 13288) Mon Sep 28 20:27:58 2015: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash
```

Please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: File a bug report or work thorough these pages - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Debugging and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/